# How to export a mongo collection to json file from java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I want to perform the mongoexport functionality within a java program. That is I want something similar to mongoexport -db myDatabase --collection Page --out Page.json

Is there a way this can be done using java programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mongoexport --host host_name --port port_number --db myDatabase --collection Page --out Page.json");
```

See [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), and mongodb should be added in your environmental variables.

Comment: It gives me a blank json file.

Comment: `mongoexport ` requires some user privileges. can you check them ?
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly. let me know if this is the code which works for you?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you